# how to do date search in mvc core c# when date format is yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: string, search, filtering, datetime-format

I have a grid in .net mvc core  that I apply a search in every column in the grid based on a search string. It works on every search string I put in EXCEPT for date strings like yyyy-mm-dd ( ie when hyphens are used).

When I put in yyyy or mm or dd individually the search works. But when I put in yyyy plus the hyphen (ie yyyy-) , it never finds any records.

Here is my c# code for the filter:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
         serviceRequests = serviceRequests.Where(s => s.Id.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
         || s.DateTimeSubmitted != null && s.DateTimeSubmitted.ToString().ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
         || s.RequestHeading != null && s.RequestHeading.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
         || s.RequestDescription != null && s.RequestDescription.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
         || s.RequestorId != null && s.RequestorId.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
         || s.RequestorFirstName != null && s.RequestorFirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
         || s.RequestorLastName != null && s.RequestorLastName.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
                        );
    }
```

How does the filter syntax have to be changed to allow for "yyyy-mm-dd" strings to be used? Why does the hyphen cause problems?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever upvoted or [accepted an answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: havent been familiar with that - read more about it now- thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `DateTimeSubmitted` is of type DateTime.  What happens if you use the `DateTime.ToString()` method? Citing from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to its equivalent
>   string representation using the formatting conventions of the current
>   culture.

So, the string representation may not what you expect, e.g. `01.01.0001 00:00:00`

I suggest to format the source with a format string like this:

```
DateTimeSubmitted.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Or another [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info- tried it - when i do that in the filter code above -it comes back with error message of 'no overload for method ToString takes 1 arguments'

Comment: Sorry, I could not test it end to end - this was a general remark about `DateTime.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was a slight twist on suggestion:

|| s.DateTimeSubmitted != null && s.DateTimeSubmitted.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())

Had to change DateTimeSubmitted.ToString to DateTimeSubmitted.Value.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd) to be able to specify formatting. - ie adding .value before .ToString

Thanks so much!

Comment: I am glad you could figure it out. However, I would be still appreciated if the effort put in could be rewarded.